# How to provide padding to the tickPosition on highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, bullet-chart

I am using `bullet chart` of `highchart`to work alike progress chart somehow i achieved to make it look like as a progress chart, but the problem is that when my series data is near to equal it gets overlapped with each other. Please take a look attached image [image: After overlap]

[image: Before overlap]

is there any way to provide padding on bullet chart so the data will not get overlapped?

```js
$("#progress").highcharts({
        chart: {
            inverted: true,
            marginLeft: 30,
            type: 'bullet'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickPositions: [0, 3000, 3100, 4000],
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: "",
            useHTML: true,//Set to true
            style: {
                width: '50px'
            }
        }, xAxis: {
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 10,
                color: '#819bc2',
                targetOptions: {
                    width: '10%'
                },
                grouping: false
            }
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        series: [{ "data": [{ "y": 4000, "target": 4000, "color": "#ccd8e9" }] }, { "data": [{ "y": 3100, "target": 3100, "color": "#ff4666" }] }, { "data": [{ "y": 3000, "target": 3000, "color": "#2F9AD0" }] }],
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderWidth: 0,
            positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
                var tooltipX = point.plotX - 40;
                var tooltipY = point.plotY - 20;
                return {
                    x: tooltipX,
                    y: tooltipY
                };
            },
            pointFormat: "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:{point.color};'>{point.y}</span>"
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/bullet.js"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

Comment: You could also use [**rotation**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.rotation): https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/jgezt8xm/7/ or [**staggerLines**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.staggerLines): https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/jgezt8xm/5/.

Comment: Thanx @ewolden `staggerLines` works.

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution with `jQuery`. There might be better ones, but it should work as wished:

```
var lastXPos = 0;
$.each($('#progress svg g text'),function(a,b)
{
  var curXPos = $(this).offset().left;
  if(curXPos - lastXPos < 50)
  {
    $(this).attr('x', (curXPos + 50));
  }
  lastXPos = curXPos;
});
```

When the last x-position of the text is within 50px of the current x-position, I just add another 50px to the current position. You can change this values according to your needs.

```js
$("#progress").highcharts({
        chart: {
            inverted: true,
            marginLeft: 30,
            type: 'bullet'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickPositions: [0, 3000, 3100, 4000],
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: "",
            useHTML: true,//Set to true
            style: {
                width: '50px'
            }
        }, xAxis: {
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 10,
                color: '#819bc2',
                targetOptions: {
                    width: '10%'
                },
                grouping: false
            }
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        series: [{ "data": [{ "y": 4000, "target": 4000, "color": "#ccd8e9" }] }, { "data": [{ "y": 3100, "target": 3100, "color": "#ff4666" }] }, { "data": [{ "y": 3000, "target": 3000, "color": "#2F9AD0" }] }],
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderWidth: 0,
            positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
                var tooltipX = point.plotX - 40;
                var tooltipY = point.plotY - 20;
                return {
                    x: tooltipX,
                    y: tooltipY
                };
            },
            pointFormat: "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:{point.color};'>{point.y}</span>"
        }
    });
    var lastXPos = 0;
    $.each($('#progress svg g text'),function(a,b)
    {
      var curXPos = $(this).offset().left;
      if(curXPos - lastXPos < 50)
      {
        $(this).attr('x', (curXPos + 50));
      }
      lastXPos = curXPos;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/bullet.js"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rotation option for yaxis label for not overlapping the text

```js
$("#progress").highcharts({
        chart: {
            inverted: true,
            marginLeft: 30,
            type: 'bullet'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickPositions: [0, 3000, 3100, 4000],
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: "",
            useHTML: true,//Set to true
           
            labels: {
                rotation : 320
            },
            
        }, xAxis: {
            minorGridLineWidth: 0,
            lineColor: 'transparent',
           
            minorTickLength: 0,
            tickLength: 0,
        },
        allowOverlap : false,
        padding : 10,
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 10,
                color: '#819bc2',
                targetOptions: {
                    width: '10%'
                },
                
                grouping: false
            }
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        series: [{ "data": [{ "y": 4000, "target": 4000, "color": "#ccd8e9" }] }, { "data": [{ "y": 3100, "target": 3100, "color": "#ff4666" }] }, { "data": [{ "y": 3000, "target": 3000, "color": "#2F9AD0" }] }],
        tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderWidth: 0,
            positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
                var tooltipX = point.plotX - 40;
                var tooltipY = point.plotY - 20;
                return {
                    x: tooltipX,
                    y: tooltipY
                };
            },
            pointFormat: "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:{point.color};'>{point.y}</span>"
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
     <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/bullet.js"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding does not work for the labels on your yAxis. This is probably a sideeffect of using [**`tickPositions`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions)

> An array defining where the ticks are laid out on the axis. This overrides the default behaviour of tickPixelInterval and tickInterval.

As an alternative solution you can use [**`rotation`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.rotation):

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    rotation: -45
  },
...
}
```

```js
$("#progress").highcharts({
  chart: {
    inverted: true,
    marginLeft: 30,
    type: 'bullet'
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [0, 3000, 3100, 4000],
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: "",
    labels: {
      rotation: -45
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderRadius: 10,
      color: '#819bc2',
      targetOptions: {
        width: '10%'
      },
      grouping: false
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    "data": [{
      "y": 4000,
      "target": 4000,
      "color": "#ccd8e9"
    }]
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "y": 3100,
      "target": 3100,
      "color": "#ff4666"
    }]
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "y": 3000,
      "target": 3000,
      "color": "#2F9AD0"
    }]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    backgroundColor: null,
    borderWidth: 0,
    positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
      var tooltipX = point.plotX - 40;
      var tooltipY = point.plotY - 20;
      return {
        x: tooltipX,
        y: tooltipY
      };
    },
    pointFormat: "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:{point.color};'>{point.y}</span>"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/bullet.js"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

**JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/jgezt8xm/7/

[image]

You can also use [**`staggerLines`**](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.staggerLines):

```
yAxis: {
  labels: {
    staggerLines: 2
  },
...
}
```

```js
$("#progress").highcharts({
  chart: {
    inverted: true,
    marginLeft: 30,
    type: 'bullet'
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    tickPositions: [0, 3000, 3100, 4000],
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    title: "",
    labels: {
      staggerLines: 2
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    minorGridLineWidth: 0,
    lineColor: 'transparent',
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    minorTickLength: 0,
    tickLength: 0
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderRadius: 10,
      color: '#819bc2',
      targetOptions: {
        width: '10%'
      },
      grouping: false
    }
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    "data": [{
      "y": 4000,
      "target": 4000,
      "color": "#ccd8e9"
    }]
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "y": 3100,
      "target": 3100,
      "color": "#ff4666"
    }]
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "y": 3000,
      "target": 3000,
      "color": "#2F9AD0"
    }]
  }],
  tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    backgroundColor: null,
    borderWidth: 0,
    positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight, point) {
      var tooltipX = point.plotX - 40;
      var tooltipY = point.plotY - 20;
      return {
        x: tooltipX,
        y: tooltipY
      };
    },
    pointFormat: "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:{point.color};'>{point.y}</span>"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/bullet.js"></script>

<div id="progress"></div>
```

**JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/jgezt8xm/5/

[image]